# how to set the size for the button in JAVA?

Tags: java, button, swt

I can't set the size for the button in the below code. If I set **b.setSize** to (2000,2000) nothing will change. Do you have any suggestions what I'm doing wrong or overlook.
Best regards

Chris

```
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
  Composite container = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
  GridLayout containerLayout = new GridLayout();
  GridData containerLayoutData = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true,     true);
  container.setLayout(containerLayout);
  container.setLayoutData(containerLayoutData);
  Tag t = new Tag("Action", 'm');    

  Button b = new Button(container, SWT.PUSH);
  GridData(GridData.HORIZONTAL_ALIGN_BEGINNING);
  b.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING ,SWT.CENTER, false,false));
  b.setText("Movie");   
  Button button2 = new Button(container, SWT.PUSH);                                                             button2.setLayoutData(newGridData(SWT.BEGINNING,SWT.CENTER,false,false));
  button2.setText("Performer");
  return container;
}
```

Comment: Hello Christian, welcome to stackoverflow.  Perhaps the grid layout overrides the size of the button.  It might be that a gridlayout comes with a configurable grid of cells and that in every cell a control can be rendered to the cell's full width and height.  It has been some time since I worked with java so I'm not sure.  Perhaps you can experiment with different layouts and post your results here.  I hope someone can help you.  Welcome, and I hope to see more posts by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't mix layouts with `setSize` - the layout will override the size with the size that it calculates.

Instead specify a width hint for the button layout:

```
Button b = new Button(container, SWT.PUSH);
GridData data = new GridData(SWT.BEGINNING, SWT.CENTER, false, false);
data.widthHint = 100;  // Width in pixels
b.setLayoutData(data);
b.setText("Movie");
```

Since your code is in a JFace `Dialog` you can also use the `convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels` or `convertWidthInCharsToPixels` methods of `Dialog` to calculate the width. For example:

```
data.widthHint = convertHorizontalDLUsToPixels(IDialogConstants.BUTTON_WIDTH);
```

You can set the height using the `heightHint` in a similar way.

Comment: Okay it works well Thank you very much I appriciate that.